# How can I grant PostgerSQL access to export a file to my desired path?

Tags: postgresql, export-to-csv, file-permissions

I've been trying to export a table to my Ubuntu Desktop using the following command:

```
\copy stock to /home/micheal/Desktop/myCSV.csv CSV HEADER
```

I get the following error: **/home/micheal/Desktop/myCSV.csv: Permission denied**

How can I grant permission to save this file? I don't want to save in the '/temp/' directory.

Comment: You have to give the user that runs `psql` permission to write to the directory (and get into all containing directories).

Comment: @Laurenz Albe. Thanks for your answer. Please, can you show me how? I'm new to psql. I couldn't proceed my present tutorial when I got to that point.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe. I have been stuck here for up to a week now.

Comment: You'll have to take some basic education about file permissions on your operating system. A Q&A forum cannot provide a tutorial or basic training.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe: I have tried the following, and it still brings back same message: sudo chmod a+rwx /home/micheal/Documents/

Comment: The missing permissions might also be on the directories above that.